# Computer Vision: Template Matching

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to detect labels with barcodes. These labels all look very similar but each label has a different barcode/wording on it.

I have tried template matching but to no avail.

One constraint that I am faced with is that there are other barcodes in the image, but I only want labels with this format of barcodes.

[image]

Could anyone hint me some other algorithms.

Thank you!

Comment: *I only want labels with this format of barcodes* what do you mean by this **format**? All bar codes have this format

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with barcodes, but you might want to have a look at [Canny Edge detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector). It's quite simple to understand and should help you in your task.

If I had to do anything like this, I would first try to rotate the image until the lines are vertical, use canny and then extract the 'on/off' pattern of each set of bars.

Answer (score 0):

This [PyImageSearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/) page is a good starting point.

To reject codes of other formats, you can use a bar code reader api, or come up with some rules regarding the format.